# SQL Server 2008 Count(Distinct CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT     
    ScheduleDays = COUNT(DISTINCT(CAST(datediff(d, 0, a.ApptStart) AS datetime)))
FROM 
    Appointments a
WHERE   
    ApptKind = 1 AND 
    --filter on current month
    a.ApptStart >= ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0),'1/1/1900')   AND
    a.ApptStart < ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0),'1/1/3000')AND
    --filter all days that aren't Friday, and then give you all Fridays that have an hour > 12.
    DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) <> 'Friday' and DATEPART(hour, a.ApptStart) > 12 AND
    --Filter on doctor
    a.ResourceID in (201)
```

This query will look through appointment start times and not count Fridays as our Docs only work a half day on Fridays. I was told that we do want to count them, but only as half days (first time around I was told to exclude them lol).

Could someone please help me with a Case statement that will count Fridays that do not have an appointment after 12noon, as half a day? I believe it will have to go in the `ScheduleDays=COUNT(DISTINCT(CAST(datediff(d,0,a.ApptStart) as datetime)))`. Perhaps we can put the Friday and after 12 filters in there instead of in the where clause if we are going to use case anyways. `ScheduleDays=COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN etc`. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Your posted query returns the number of days in the current month where a doctor has a scheduled appointment which is not on a Friday and in the afternoon. No Friday appointments are counted, and no morning appointments are counted. Are you asking for a query which does the same appointment counting, but for only before noon if the appointment is on a Friday, and at any time on other days?

Comment: Hmm, as you can tell I am new to this SQL stuff. I want it to count all days that have an appointment. If the Friday has only appointments in the morning (cuttoff at noon) then we count it as a half day. The idea here is to return the number of days the doc has appointments and counting fridays as half days. We are going to use this to set benchmarks for them.

Comment: Can you give your question a better, more descriptive title? It looks like a question that could be of use to other users, so would be a shame if it will not be found by them because of the title :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really count half things using `count`, so that is not the way to go.  But, you can do it with arithmetic.  I think something like this:

```
select (count(distinct (case when DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) <> 'Friday'
                             then cast(a.apptstart as date)
                        end)
             ) +
        0.5 * count(distinct (case when DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) = 'Friday'
                                   then cast(a.apptstart as date)
                              end)
                   )
       ) as ScheduleDays
```

If the docs only work on Fridays for half a day, I don't think you need to check for the time of the appointment.  Of course, you can if you like by adding it into the second `count`.

Note that to count days, I used the simpler syntax of casting the `datetime` to a `date`.

EDIT:

With the hour check:

```
select (count(distinct (case when DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) <> 'Friday'
                             then cast(a.apptstart as date)
                        end)
             ) +
        0.5 * count(distinct (case when DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) = 'Friday' and  DATEPART(hour, a.ApptStart) <= 12 
                                   then cast(a.apptstart as date)
                              end)
                   )
       ) as ScheduleDays
```

Comment: Haha awsome guys! That makes a lot of sense. If I wanted to add the check for time I would add it after ='Friday' _________ then etc. So and DATEPART(hour, a.ApptStart) > 12. This works like Java right? Where the and applies to both the = 'Friday' and the >12?